# Type projection alias fails with type bounds

Tags: scala, types

I want a type projection alias using type bounds and higher-kinded types, but it fails unexpectedly. Tried in scala 2.12.8 and 2.13.0

The following works:

```
object Testing {

  trait One[A] {
    trait Two[B <: A]
  }

  type Test = One[Int]#Two[Int]
}
```

and the following fails:

```
object Testing {

  trait One[A] {
    type Two[B <: A] = Altogether[A, B]
  }

  trait Altogether[A, B <: A]

  type Test = One[Int]#Two[Int]
}
```

with error

```
type arguments [Int] do not conform to type Two's type parameter bounds [B <: A]
```

I would expect the second example to compile too.

The following works:

```
type Test = Altogether[Int, Int]
```

Can anybody come up with an alternative?

Comment: In dotty 0.16 it compiles :) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zSyzQzwwTGO2TOifSHYx8g

Comment: Given the error message (which you should have included) it certainly looks like a bug to me. It also remains if you remove type bound from `Altogether` (but not from `Two`).

Comment: SO is a wrong place to report about bugs https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: Apologies, I will update the question to contain an actual question! And the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace `trait` with `type` it works as expected:

```
type One[A] = {
    type Two[B <: A] = Altogether[A, B]
}

trait Altogether[A, B <: A]

type Test = One[Int]#Two[Int]
```

Tested with [Scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dGKrmp95Rwqqi8prJ7HGHw).

Comment: This does resolve the problem as stated in the question, thanks!. Ideally though I would like them to be traits so I can create instances of them. I don't think that is possible with your solution? Happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: @Gesar As Dmytro Mitin said previously it's probably compiler bug, so maybe it will be fixed in next version of Scala 2 (2.14?). It's already compiling with Scala 3 (but it is yet to be released in 2020).